# I want to convert this code from SAS to ECL(HPCC)

Tags: sas, hpcc, hpcc-ecl

Can Somebody please explain me the meaning &, && , % in this SAS code.
I want to convert this code to ECL(HPCC). Thanks

```
PROC SQL;
create table  &RD (compress=binary) as
select a.*,b.Staff_tag2
from &RD a left join (select DISTINCT ucic_id , 1 as Staff_TAG2 
from    BAL.BAL_&DDMMYYYY1 where prod_code = '102')b
on a.ucic_id=b.ucic_id; 
QUIT;
```

---

```
%macro rd();
%do i=1 %to 12;
proc sql;
create table rd.RD_Closed_&&ddmmyyyy&i (compress=binary) as
select V_F_ACCT_ACCT_NUMBER as acct_no,
V_F_ACCT_FIC_CUSTOMER_REF_CODE as ucic_id
from edw.fct_all_accounts_summary
where business_dt eq &&yyyymmdd&i and V_F_ACCT_SOURCE_SYSTEM =  'FINWARERD' AND F_F_ACCT_CLOSED_IND eq 'Y';
quit;
%end;
%mend;
option mprint;
```

Comment: Code conversion is off topic here, though you're not exactly asking for that.  However, what you are asking is something trivially found by learning even a little about SAS.  Go read a tutorial on SAS (particularly the SAS Macro language, it looks like) and then come back with any questions you may have informed by some understanding of the language.

Answer (score 2):

& and && is the beginning of macro variables. They resolve to a value. The value they resolve to depends how they are defined. An example could be:

%let var=test;

in this case &var resolves to test. But there are other ways to initiate macro variables. The %-sign pretty much means that it belongs to the macro languages. There is much to say about SAS macros but i am not sure exactly how much info your after.